# missing headers in my PHP $_SERVER variable

Tags: php, apache, nginx, server

When i send the request to a different server ( web-hook.site ) it displays the following headers

```
Headers
connection  close
baggage     sentry-environment=production,sentry-public_key=bb95332ee3d06b5094e1e79ed984e334,sentry-trace_id=4fc58931f2cc45468cbf7fea19ffe906
sentry-trace    4fc58931f2cc45468cbf7fea19ffe906-936f4ad0d25fe668
accept-encoding     gzip, compress, deflate, br
content-length  3434
host    webhook.site
request-starttime   302316678
authorization   fa603ad31eb6026373b531081f35b4c0
x-salla-security-strategy   Token
user-agent  Salla Webhook v2.0
timestamp   1697249626
content-type    application/json
accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
```

But the same request if directed to my server displays these php headers ( the header called authorization is missing in it )

```
Array
(
    [USER] => quirky-meitner_3mz6wjlmnve
    [HOME] => /var/www/vhosts/websdemand.com
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /system/salla.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /system/salla.php
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 40624
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/vhosts/websdemand.com/httpdocs/system/salla.php
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/vhosts/websdemand.com/httpdocs
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => https
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/vhosts/websdemand.com/httpdocs
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 18.157.170.48
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 92.204.129.177
    [SERVER_NAME] => www.websdemand.com
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    [HTTP_BAGGAGE] => sentry-environment=production,sentry-public_key=bb95332ee3d06b5094e1e79ed984e334,sentry-trace_id=31437399aca54b2caa1ecd63ccebe3d4
    [HTTP_SENTRY_TRACE] => 31437399aca54b2caa1ecd63ccebe3d4-b19ce003b608452d
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, compress, deflate, br
    [HTTP_REQUEST_STARTTIME] => 2257, 673457278
    [HTTP_X_SALLA_SECURITY_STRATEGY] => Token
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Salla Webhook v2.0
    [HTTP_TIMESTAMP] => 1697251377
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/json
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => application/json, text/plain, */*
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 3464
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [HTTP_X_ACCEL_INTERNAL] => /internal-nginx-static-location
    [HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => 18.157.170.48
    [HTTP_HOST] => www.websdemand.com
    [proxy-nokeepalive] => 1
    [HTTPS] => on
    [PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY] => 0
    [PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY] => 0
    [PERL5LIB] => /usr/share/awstats/lib:/usr/share/awstats/plugins
    [SCRIPT_URI] => https://www.websdemand.com/system/salla.php
    [SCRIPT_URL] => /system/salla.php
    [UNIQUE_ID] => ZSoAMpNgor2GsyidS4TiwQAAABA
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [PHP_SELF] => /system/salla.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1697251378.3968
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1697251378
)
```

What could be the reason ?

I have this webhook which is sending authorization token which needs to be computed in the following manner

```
<?php 
$requestHMAC = $_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'];
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');

$computedHMAC = hash_hmac('sha256', $requestBody, $secret_key);

if ($requestHMAC === $computedHMAC) {
  // do stuff
  write_file("HMAC is correct", "a+");
}
else {
    write_file("HMAC is not correct", "a+");
}
?>
```

Comment: My guess is the server might be ignoring it because the syntax for authorizations is as follows Authorization : <scheme> <authorization-parameters>

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Comment: Wheat web server setup are you using - Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc? As tomexsans says, the header may be being stripped as invalid before it even gets to PHP, and if you can't fix the request, the workaround will depend on the server.